# Return All Rows if Field is null or blank

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

How do I make this return all results if @title is null or if its blank ''?

```
@title varchar

AS

SELECT *
FROM mydb
Where (Title = @title)
```

Ive been trying to mess around with different ways but I always get no rows returns. I just need to return all the rows, if nothing is inputed into the parameter.

Answer (score 4):

Add:

```
...
OR @Title IS NULL
OR @Title = ''
```

The `OR` makes it inclusive, and there's no way that you will have `@Title` meet more than one of those three criteria (unless your `Title` field has `NULL` or blank values).

Comment: @Bob, this will definitely work but it may be overkill if you really only are concerned about nothing being passed in for the parameter

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
IF LEN(@title) > 0 THEN
BEGIN 

  SELECT * FROM mydb t
   WHERE t.title = @title

END
ELSE
BEGIN 

  SELECT * FROM mydb 

END
```

You can use:

```
SELECT *
  FROM mydb
 WHERE (LEN(@title) = 0 OR t.title = @title)
```

...to only use the `@title` variable if it's not zero length or NULL, but the statement is not sargable -- it won't perform as well as breaking out the statement to be only what it needs to be for the situation.